# custom kernel, multimedia chortcuts for asus 1225c

Tags: kernel, shortcut-keys

several minutes compiled my custom kernel, checked everythink and it seems multimedia keys doesn't work and not showed by xet and showkey. In my my opinion i have something disabled that corespondend to keys. On section x86 others drivers leaved my PC and several others support. For now only brightness control work, not volume control...

Doesn't anybody can give i bit information on what section i should look in order enable shortcuts again ?

```
PC: Intel Atom 1225c
fn+ f10 = mute sound
fn+f11 = lower volume
fn+f12 = upper volume
fn+f9 = disable touchpad
fn+f5= brightness down (works)
fn+f5=brightness up (works)
fn+f2= wireless on/off(works)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my compiled kernel is 3.2.0 and it's seems on that date then kernel was released my PC wasn't in market at all... Looked at changelog and found that in version 3.2.14 add more asus hotkeys.

Edit:

Founded solution, it seems i haven't enabled `CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL` = `Prompt for development and/or incomplete code/drivers` if it enabled it expose:

1. `CONFIG_ASUS_NB_WMI` (Asus Notebook WMI Driver (EXPERIMENTAL))
2. `CONFIG_ASUS_WMI` (ASUS WMI Driver (EXPERIMENTAL))

After all, sulotion founded, marking this answer as answered. Hopefully, maybe someone this research will be helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

These are `hotkeys`, and are managed by udev.

If you freshly compiled your kernel and the hotkeys do not work, then udev is not running or not communicating with the kernel. The brightness control bypasses udev, which is the reason it works. Multimedia hotkeys require udev to be running.

Comment: udev working/worked fine, solution posted below, thanks for trying to help.